# flutter app freezes when cleaning too many variables

Tags: flutter, dart

after i updated my flutter to 3.3.8 i was in 3.0.0

I have a function that cleans several variables whenever I run it, the app crashes and closes, in the windows version the app consumes all the machine's ram memory

follow my function:

LimparVariaveis()

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:extended_masked_text/extended_masked_text.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String variavelum = '';
String variaveldois = '';
String variaveltres = '';
String variavelquatro = '';
String variavelcinco = '';
String variavelseis = '';
String variavelsete = '';
String variaveloito = '';
String variavelnove = '';
String variaveldez  = '';



var hora_inicial;

Timer timer;
Timer timerDois;
Timer timerTres;

int contRodarPesquisas = 0;
int contRodarSimulacao = 0;

String ValorRestricao = 'Nível de restrição*';
String cadastro_inviavel = 'Status Da Pasta*';

bool TimerCancel = false;
bool ParaTimers = false;

String InfoPassadasSimulacao = '';
String InfoPassadasFGTS = '';
String InfoPassadasValorDocumentacao = '';
String InfoPassadasValorPrazo = '';
String InfoPassadasEntregaDocs = '';
String InfoPassadasTaxaJuros = '';

int docx = 0;
int jpg  = 0;

String ObsObrigatorias ='';

var controllerObservacoes = TextEditingController();
var controllerIndicacoes = TextEditingController();
String OrigemAtendimento = 'Origem';
bool PesquisaRunning = false ;
//#######################Doc Apresentados############################
var DocApresentadosRG = '';
var DocApresentadosCPF = '';
var DocApresentadosCNH = '';
var DocApresentadosCertidaoEstadoCivil = '';
var DocApresentadosComprovanteRenda = '';
var DocApresentadosCTPS = '';
var DocApresentadosNumPis = '';
var DocApresentadosCertidaoIR = '';

var DocApresentadosRG_C = '';
var DocApresentadosCPF_C = '';
var DocApresentadosCNH_C = '';
var DocApresentadosCertidaoEstadoCivil_C = '';
var DocApresentadosComprovanteRenda_C = '';
var DocApresentadosCTPS_C = '';
var DocApresentadosNumPis_C = '';
var DocApresentadosCertidaoIR_C = '';

var DocApresentadosComprovanteResidencia = '';
var DocApresentadosCertidaoDependentes = '';
//TextEditingController controllerDataNascimento = TextEditingController();
//TextEditingController controllerDataNascimento_C = TextEditingController();
//#######################TELEFONE ENDERECO############################
var controllerCEP = new MaskedTextController(mask: '00000-000');
var controllerLogradouro = TextEditingController();
var controllerNumero = TextEditingController();
var controllerBairro = TextEditingController();
var controllerComplemento = TextEditingController();
var controllerUF = TextEditingController();
var controllerCidadeEndereco = TextEditingController();

var controllerDDDCelular = new MaskedTextController(mask: '00');
var controllerCelular = new MaskedTextController(mask: '000000000');

var controllerDDDTelefone = new MaskedTextController(mask:  '00');
var controllerTelefone = new MaskedTextController(mask: '000000000');

var controllerDDDTelefone2 = new MaskedTextController(mask:  '00');
var controllerTelefone2 = new MaskedTextController(mask: '000000000');

var controllerDDDTelefone3 = new MaskedTextController(mask: '00');
var controllerTelefone3 = new MaskedTextController(mask:'000000000');

var controllerEmail = TextEditingController();
//###################################################
//#######################CADSATRO2############################
var ContaCaixa = "não";
var controllerNumeroContaCaixa = TextEditingController();

var FuncionarioPublico = "não";
var controllerFuncionarioDataInicio = TextEditingController();
var controllerFuncionarioOcupacao = TextEditingController();
var controllerFuncionarioTipo = TextEditingController();

var RendaInformal = "não";
var controllerRendaInformalAtividade = TextEditingController();
var controllerRendaInformalValor = TextEditingController();
var controllerRendaInformalObservacoes = TextEditingController();
var controllerRendaInformalDataInicio = TextEditingController();
var RendaInformalTipoComprovacao = "";
var RendaInformalSelect  = 'Tipo de Comprovação';
//########################################################
//##########################CADASTRO#######################
var controllerNomePrincipal = TextEditingController();
//var controllerRGPrincipal = TextEditingController();
var EstadoCivilPrincipal  = 'Estado Civil*';
var EscolaridadePrincipal  = 'Escolaridade*';
var EscolaridadeNivelPrincipal  = 'Escolaridade Nivel*';
var EscolaridadeSituacaoPrincipal  = 'Escolaridade Situacao*';

var controllerDataNascimento = new MaskedTextController(mask: '00/00/0000');

var controllerNomeParticipante = TextEditingController();
//var controllerRGParticipante = TextEditingController();
var EstadoCivilParticipante  = 'Estado Civil*';
var EscolaridadeParticipante  = 'Escolaridade*';
var EscolaridadeNivelParticipante  = 'Escolaridade Nivel*';
var EscolaridadeSituacaoParticipante  = 'Escolaridade Situacao*';
var controllerDataNascimento_C = new MaskedTextController(mask: '00/00/0000');

//#####################################################

var controllerRenda = MoneyMaskedTextController(decimalSeparator: ',', thousandSeparator: '.'); //after
var controllerValorImovel = MoneyMaskedTextController(decimalSeparator: ',', thousandSeparator: '.'); //after
//var controllerImovel = MoneyMaskedTextController(decimalSeparator: ',', thousandSeparator: '.'); //after

var FCpfPrincipal = '';
var FCpfParticipante = '';

//var TresAnosFGTS = "sim";
//var dependentes = "sim";

var TresAnosFGTS = "";
var dependentes = "";

var Empreendimento = "";
var IsSBPE = "";

var cidadeSelect = "" ;
var ValorImovel = "";
var QtdParticipantes = "1";
var faixa = "1,5";
var parametrofaixa = 'auto';
//var FDataNascimentoPrincipal = '';
//var FDataNascimentoParticipante = '';

var AvaliacaoResult = '';
var AvaliacaoResultHtml = '';

var AvaliacaoResult_C = '';
var AvaliacaoResultHtml_C = '';

var CadastralPrincipal = '';
var CadastralParticipante = '';

var HTMLPrincipal = '';
var HTMLParticipante = '';


var CadMutPrincipal = '';
var CadMutParticipante = '';

var CadMutHTMLPrincipal = '';
var CadMutHTMLParticipante = '';

var IrPrincipal = '';
var IrParticipante = '';

var IrHTMLPrincipal = '';
var IrHTMLParticipante = '';

var CNDPrincipal = '';
var CNDParticipante = '';

var CNDHTMLPrincipal = '';
var CNDHTMLParticipante = '';


var feitoSac = false;
var feitoPrice = false;

var feitoSacDois = false;
var feitoPriceDois = false;

var FeitoConstrutor = false;


var FeitoIR = 0;
var FeitoIR_c = 0;

var FeitoCND = 0;
var FeitoCND_c = 0;

bool PodeTentarSmular = false;
bool PodeTentarConsultar = true;

var SistemaAmortizacaoSAC ="_";
var FaixaSac = '_';
var ValorImovelSAC ="_";
var ValorEntradaSAC ="_";
var DescontoSAC ="_";
var PrazoSAC ="_";
var FGTSTresAnoSAC ="_";
var NumeroParticipantesSAC ="_";
var DependentesSAC ="_";
var RendaUsavaSAC ="_";
var ValorFinanciamentoSAC ="_";
var PrazoMaximoSAC ="_";
var CotaMaxFinanciamentoSAC ="_";
var EntradaAtualizadaSAC ="_";
var DespesaCartorariaSAC ="_";
var ApoliceSeguroSAC ="_";
var SeguroVistaSAC ="_";
var TarifasSAC ="_";
var IOFSAC ="_";
var totalTaxasAVistaSAC ="_";
var AmortizacaoJurosSAC ="_";
var SeguroDFISAC ="_";
var SeguroMIPSAC ="_";
var TotalSegurosSAC ="_";
var TaxaAdministracaoSAC ="_";
var TaxaRiscoCreditoSAC ="_";
var TaxaOperacionalMensalSAC ="_";
var TotalComponentesSAC ="_";
var PrimeiraPrestacaoSAC ="_";
var JurosNominaisSAC ="_";
var JurosEfeticosSAC ="_";
var HtmlSac = "";

var SistemaAmortizacaoPRICE ="_";
var FaixaPRICE = '_';
var ValorImovelPRICE ="_";
var ValorEntradaPRICE ="_";
var DescontoPRICE ="_";
var PrazoPRICE ="_";
var FGTSTresAnoPRICE ="_";
var NumeroParticipantesPRICE ="_";
var DependentesPRICE ="_";
var RendaUsavaPRICE ="_";
var ValorFinanciamentoPRICE ="_";
var PrazoMaximoPRICE ="_";
var CotaMaxFinanciamentoPRICE ="_";
var EntradaAtualizadaPRICE ="_";
var DespesaCartorariaPRICE ="_";
var ApoliceSeguroPRICE ="_";
var SeguroVistaPRICE ="_";
var TarifasPRICE ="_";
var IOFPRICE ="_";
var totalTaxasAVistaPRICE ="_";
var AmortizacaoJurosPRICE ="_";
var SeguroDFIPRICE ="_";
var SeguroMIPPRICE ="_";
var TotalSegurosPRICE ="_";
var TaxaAdministracaoPRICE ="_";
var TaxaRiscoCreditoPRICE ="_";
var TaxaOperacionalMensalPRICE ="_";
var TotalComponentesPRICE ="_";
var PrimeiraPrestacaoPRICE ="_";
var JurosNominaisPRICE ="_";
var JurosEfeticosPRICE ="_";
var HtmlPrice = "";

var ValoresSac = new List<ModelsSimulados>();
var ValoresPRICE = new List<ModelsSimulados>();

var ValoresSimuladodoisPRICE = new List<ModelsSimulados>();
var ValoresSimuladodoisSac = new List<ModelsSimulados>();


var SistemaAmortizacaoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var FaixaPRICESimuladodois = '_';
var ValorImovelPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var ValorEntradaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var DescontoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var PrazoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var FGTSTresAnoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var NumeroParticipantesPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var DependentesPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var RendaUsavaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var ValorFinanciamentoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var PrazoMaximoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var CotaMaxFinanciamentoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var EntradaAtualizadaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var DespesaCartorariaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var ApoliceSeguroPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var SeguroVistaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var TarifasPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var IOFPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var totalTaxasAVistaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var AmortizacaoJurosPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var SeguroDFIPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var SeguroMIPPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var TotalSegurosPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var TaxaAdministracaoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var TaxaRiscoCreditoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var TaxaOperacionalMensalPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var TotalComponentesPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var PrimeiraPrestacaoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var JurosNominaisPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var JurosEfeticosPRICESimuladodois ="_";
var HtmlPriceSimuladodois = "";

var SistemaAmortizacaoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var FaixaSacSimuladodois = '_';
var ValorImovelSACSimuladodois ="_";
var ValorEntradaSACSimuladodois ="_";
var DescontoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var PrazoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var FGTSTresAnoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var NumeroParticipantesSACSimuladodois ="_";
var DependentesSACSimuladodois ="_";
var RendaUsavaSACSimuladodois ="_";
var ValorFinanciamentoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var PrazoMaximoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var CotaMaxFinanciamentoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var EntradaAtualizadaSACSimuladodois ="_";
var DespesaCartorariaSACSimuladodois ="_";
var ApoliceSeguroSACSimuladodois ="_";
var SeguroVistaSACSimuladodois ="_";
var TarifasSACSimuladodois ="_";
var IOFSACSimuladodois ="_";
var totalTaxasAVistaSACSimuladodois ="_";
var AmortizacaoJurosSACSimuladodois ="_";
var SeguroDFISACSimuladodois ="_";
var SeguroMIPSACSimuladodois ="_";
var TotalSegurosSACSimuladodois ="_";
var TaxaAdministracaoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var TaxaRiscoCreditoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var TaxaOperacionalMensalSACSimuladodois ="_";
var TotalComponentesSACSimuladodois ="_";
var PrimeiraPrestacaoSACSimuladodois ="_";
var JurosNominaisSACSimuladodois ="_";
var JurosEfeticosSACSimuladodois ="_";
var HtmlSacSimuladodois = "";




class ModelsSimulados {
  String valorImovel;
  String prazoMaximo;
  String sistemaAmortizacao;
  String cotaMaxFinanciamento;
  String valorEntrada;
  String desconto;
  String entradaAtualizada;
  String prazo;
  String valorFinanciamento;
  String despesaCartoraria;
  String apoliceSeguro;
  String seguroVista;
  String tarifas;
  String iOF;
  String totalTaxasAVista;
  String amortizacaoJuros;
  String seguroDFI;
  String seguroMIP;
  String totalSeguros;
  String taxaAdministracao;
  String taxaRiscoCredito;
  String taxaOperacionalMensal;
  String totalComponentes;
  String primeiraPrestacao;
  String jurosNominais;
  String jurosEfeticos;

  ModelsSimulados(
      {this.valorImovel,
        this.prazoMaximo,
        this.sistemaAmortizacao,
        this.cotaMaxFinanciamento,
        this.valorEntrada,
        this.desconto,
        this.entradaAtualizada,
        this.prazo,
        this.valorFinanciamento,
        this.despesaCartoraria,
        this.apoliceSeguro,
        this.seguroVista,
        this.tarifas,
        this.iOF,
        this.totalTaxasAVista,
        this.amortizacaoJuros,
        this.seguroDFI,
        this.seguroMIP,
        this.totalSeguros,
        this.taxaAdministracao,
        this.taxaRiscoCredito,
        this.taxaOperacionalMensal,
        this.totalComponentes,
        this.primeiraPrestacao,
        this.jurosNominais,
        this.jurosEfeticos});

  ModelsSimulados.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    valorImovel = json['ValorImovel'];
    prazoMaximo = json['PrazoMaximo'];
    sistemaAmortizacao = json['SistemaAmortizacao'];
    cotaMaxFinanciamento = json['CotaMaxFinanciamento'];
    valorEntrada = json['ValorEntrada'];
    desconto = json['Desconto'];
    entradaAtualizada = json['EntradaAtualizada'];
    prazo = json['Prazo'];
    valorFinanciamento = json['ValorFinanciamento'];
    despesaCartoraria = json['DespesaCartoraria'];
    apoliceSeguro = json['ApoliceSeguro'];
    seguroVista = json['SeguroVista'];
    tarifas = json['Tarifas'];
    iOF = json['IOF'];
    totalTaxasAVista = json['totalTaxasAVista'];
    amortizacaoJuros = json['AmortizacaoJuros'];
    seguroDFI = json['SeguroDFI'];
    seguroMIP = json['SeguroMIP'];
    totalSeguros = json['TotalSeguros'];
    taxaAdministracao = json['TaxaAdministracao'];
    taxaRiscoCredito = json['TaxaRiscoCredito'];
    taxaOperacionalMensal = json['TaxaOperacionalMensal'];
    totalComponentes = json['TotalComponentes'];
    primeiraPrestacao = json['PrimeiraPrestacao'];
    jurosNominais = json['JurosNominais'];
    jurosEfeticos = json['JurosEfeticos'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['ValorImovel'] = this.valorImovel;
    data['PrazoMaximo'] = this.prazoMaximo;
    data['SistemaAmortizacao'] = this.sistemaAmortizacao;
    data['CotaMaxFinanciamento'] = this.cotaMaxFinanciamento;
    data['ValorEntrada'] = this.valorEntrada;
    data['Desconto'] = this.desconto;
    data['EntradaAtualizada'] = this.entradaAtualizada;
    data['Prazo'] = this.prazo;
    data['ValorFinanciamento'] = this.valorFinanciamento;
    data['DespesaCartoraria'] = this.despesaCartoraria;
    data['ApoliceSeguro'] = this.apoliceSeguro;
    data['SeguroVista'] = this.seguroVista;
    data['Tarifas'] = this.tarifas;
    data['IOF'] = this.iOF;
    data['totalTaxasAVista'] = this.totalTaxasAVista;
    data['AmortizacaoJuros'] = this.amortizacaoJuros;
    data['SeguroDFI'] = this.seguroDFI;
    data['SeguroMIP'] = this.seguroMIP;
    data['TotalSeguros'] = this.totalSeguros;
    data['TaxaAdministracao'] = this.taxaAdministracao;
    data['TaxaRiscoCredito'] = this.taxaRiscoCredito;
    data['TaxaOperacionalMensal'] = this.taxaOperacionalMensal;
    data['TotalComponentes'] = this.totalComponentes;
    data['PrimeiraPrestacao'] = this.primeiraPrestacao;
    data['JurosNominais'] = this.jurosNominais;
    data['JurosEfeticos'] = this.jurosEfeticos;
    return data;
  }
}








LimparVariaveis(){

  variavelum = '';
  variaveldois = '';
  variaveltres = '';
  variavelquatro = '';
  variavelcinco = '';
  variavelseis = '';
  variavelsete = '';
  variaveloito = '';
  variavelnove = '';
  variaveldez  = '';
  PodeTentarConsultar = true;
  FCpfPrincipal = '';
  FCpfParticipante = '';
  PodeTentarConsultar = true;
  FCpfPrincipal = '';
  FCpfParticipante = '';
  contRodarPesquisas = 0;
  contRodarSimulacao = 0;

  hora_inicial;

  ValorRestricao = 'Nível de restrição*';
  cadastro_inviavel = 'Status Da Pasta*';

  InfoPassadasSimulacao = '';
  InfoPassadasFGTS = '';
  InfoPassadasValorDocumentacao = '';
  InfoPassadasValorPrazo = '';
  InfoPassadasEntregaDocs = '';
  InfoPassadasTaxaJuros = '';

  docx = 0;
  jpg  = 0;

  ObsObrigatorias ='';
  controllerObservacoes.text = '';
  controllerIndicacoes.text = '';
  OrigemAtendimento = 'Origem';
  PesquisaRunning = false ;

  DocApresentadosRG = '';
  DocApresentadosCPF = '';
  DocApresentadosCNH = '';
  DocApresentadosCertidaoEstadoCivil = '';
  DocApresentadosComprovanteRenda = '';
  DocApresentadosCTPS = '';
  DocApresentadosNumPis = '';
  DocApresentadosCertidaoIR = '';












//#######################Doc Apresentados############################


  DocApresentadosRG_C = '';
  DocApresentadosCPF_C = '';
  DocApresentadosCNH_C = '';
  DocApresentadosCertidaoEstadoCivil_C = '';
  DocApresentadosComprovanteRenda_C = '';
  DocApresentadosCTPS_C = '';
  DocApresentadosNumPis_C = '';
  DocApresentadosCertidaoIR_C = '';

  DocApresentadosComprovanteResidencia = '';
  DocApresentadosCertidaoDependentes = '';



//#######################TELEFONE ENDERECO############################
  controllerCEP.text = '';
  controllerLogradouro.text = '';
  controllerNumero.text = '';
  controllerBairro.text = '';
  controllerComplemento.text = '';
  controllerUF.text = '';
  controllerCidadeEndereco.text = '';

  controllerDDDCelular.text = '';
  controllerCelular.text = '';

  controllerDDDTelefone.text = '';
  controllerTelefone.text = '';

  controllerDDDTelefone2.text = '';
  controllerTelefone2.text = '';

  controllerDDDTelefone3.text = '';
  controllerTelefone3.text = '';
  controllerEmail.text = '';
//###################################################
//#######################CADSATRO2############################
  ContaCaixa = "não";
  controllerNumeroContaCaixa.text = '';

  FuncionarioPublico = "não";
  controllerFuncionarioDataInicio.text = '';
  controllerFuncionarioOcupacao.text = '';
  controllerFuncionarioTipo.text = '';

  RendaInformal = "não";
  controllerValorImovel.text = '';
  controllerRendaInformalAtividade.text = '';
  controllerRendaInformalValor.text = '';
  controllerRendaInformalObservacoes.text = '';
  controllerRendaInformalDataInicio.text = '';
  RendaInformalTipoComprovacao = "";
  RendaInformalSelect  = 'Tipo de Comprovação';
//########################################################
//##########################CADASTRO#######################
  controllerNomePrincipal.text = '';
//var controllerRGPrincipal = TextEditingController();
  EstadoCivilPrincipal  = 'Estado Civil*';
  EscolaridadePrincipal  = 'Escolaridade*';
  EscolaridadeNivelPrincipal  = 'Escolaridade Nivel*';
  EscolaridadeSituacaoPrincipal  = 'Escolaridade Situacao*';


  controllerNomeParticipante.text = '';
//var controllerRGParticipante = TextEditingController();
  EstadoCivilParticipante  = 'Estado Civil*';
  EscolaridadeParticipante  = 'Escolaridade*';
  EscolaridadeNivelParticipante  = 'Escolaridade Nivel*';
  EscolaridadeSituacaoParticipante  = 'Escolaridade Situacao*';


//#####################################################

  controllerRenda.text = '';
//var controllerImovel = MoneyMaskedTextController(decimalSeparator: ',', thousandSeparator: '.'); //after

  TresAnosFGTS = "";
  dependentes = "";

  Empreendimento = "";
  IsSBPE = "";
  cidadeSelect = "" ;
  ValorImovel = "";
  //QtdParticipantes = "1";
  faixa = "1,5";
  parametrofaixa = 'auto';
//var FDataNascimentoPrincipal = '';
//var FDataNascimentoParticipante = '';

  CadastralPrincipal = '';
  CadastralParticipante = '';

  HTMLPrincipal = '';
  HTMLParticipante = '';


  CadMutPrincipal = '';
  CadMutParticipante = '';

  CadMutHTMLPrincipal = '';
  CadMutHTMLParticipante = '';

  IrPrincipal = '';
  IrParticipante = '';

  IrHTMLPrincipal = '';
  IrHTMLParticipante = '';

  CNDPrincipal = '';
  CNDParticipante = '';

  CNDHTMLPrincipal = '';
  CNDHTMLParticipante = '';

  AvaliacaoResult = "";
  AvaliacaoResult_C = "";

  AvaliacaoResultHtml = "";
  AvaliacaoResultHtml_C = "";

  FeitoConstrutor = false;
  feitoPrice = false;
  feitoSac = false;
  feitoPriceDois = false;
  feitoSacDois = false;

  PodeTentarSmular = false;

  SistemaAmortizacaoSAC ="_";
  FaixaSac = '_';
  ValorImovelSAC ="_";
  ValorEntradaSAC ="_";
  DescontoSAC ="_";
  PrazoSAC ="_";
  FGTSTresAnoSAC ="_";
  NumeroParticipantesSAC ="_";
  DependentesSAC ="_";
  RendaUsavaSAC ="_";
  ValorFinanciamentoSAC ="_";
  PrazoMaximoSAC ="_";
  CotaMaxFinanciamentoSAC ="_";
  EntradaAtualizadaSAC ="_";
  DespesaCartorariaSAC ="_";
  ApoliceSeguroSAC ="_";
  SeguroVistaSAC ="_";
  TarifasSAC ="_";
  IOFSAC ="_";
  totalTaxasAVistaSAC ="_";
  AmortizacaoJurosSAC ="_";
  SeguroDFISAC ="_";
  SeguroMIPSAC ="_";
  TotalSegurosSAC ="_";
  TaxaAdministracaoSAC ="_";
  TaxaRiscoCreditoSAC ="_";
  TaxaOperacionalMensalSAC ="_";
  TotalComponentesSAC ="_";
  PrimeiraPrestacaoSAC ="_";
  JurosNominaisSAC ="_";
  JurosEfeticosSAC ="_";
  HtmlSac = "";

  SistemaAmortizacaoPRICE ="_";
  FaixaPRICE = '_';
  ValorImovelPRICE ="_";
  ValorEntradaPRICE ="_";
  DescontoPRICE ="_";
  PrazoPRICE ="_";
  FGTSTresAnoPRICE ="_";
  NumeroParticipantesPRICE ="_";
  DependentesPRICE ="_";
  RendaUsavaPRICE ="_";
  ValorFinanciamentoPRICE ="_";
  PrazoMaximoPRICE ="_";
  CotaMaxFinanciamentoPRICE ="_";
  EntradaAtualizadaPRICE ="_";
  DespesaCartorariaPRICE ="_";
  ApoliceSeguroPRICE ="_";
  SeguroVistaPRICE ="_";
  TarifasPRICE ="_";
  IOFPRICE ="_";
  totalTaxasAVistaPRICE ="_";
  AmortizacaoJurosPRICE ="_";
  SeguroDFIPRICE ="_";
  SeguroMIPPRICE ="_";
  TotalSegurosPRICE ="_";
  TaxaAdministracaoPRICE ="_";
  TaxaRiscoCreditoPRICE ="_";
  TaxaOperacionalMensalPRICE ="_";
  TotalComponentesPRICE ="_";
  PrimeiraPrestacaoPRICE ="_";
  JurosNominaisPRICE ="_";
  JurosEfeticosPRICE ="_";
  HtmlPrice = "";

  ValoresSac = new List<ModelsSimulados>();
  ValoresPRICE = new List<ModelsSimulados>();

  FeitoIR = 0;
  FeitoIR_c = 0;

  FeitoCND = 0;
  FeitoCND_c = 0;

  SistemaAmortizacaoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  FaixaSacSimuladodois = '_';
  ValorImovelSACSimuladodois ="_";
  ValorEntradaSACSimuladodois ="_";
  DescontoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  PrazoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  FGTSTresAnoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  NumeroParticipantesSACSimuladodois ="_";
  DependentesSACSimuladodois ="_";
  RendaUsavaSACSimuladodois ="_";
  ValorFinanciamentoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  PrazoMaximoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  CotaMaxFinanciamentoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  EntradaAtualizadaSACSimuladodois ="_";
  DespesaCartorariaSACSimuladodois ="_";
  ApoliceSeguroSACSimuladodois ="_";
  SeguroVistaSACSimuladodois ="_";
  TarifasSACSimuladodois ="_";
  IOFSACSimuladodois ="_";
  totalTaxasAVistaSACSimuladodois ="_";
  AmortizacaoJurosSACSimuladodois ="_";
  SeguroDFISACSimuladodois ="_";
  SeguroMIPSACSimuladodois ="_";
  TotalSegurosSACSimuladodois ="_";
  TaxaAdministracaoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  TaxaRiscoCreditoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  TaxaOperacionalMensalSACSimuladodois ="_";
  TotalComponentesSACSimuladodois ="_";
  PrimeiraPrestacaoSACSimuladodois ="_";
  JurosNominaisSACSimuladodois ="_";
  JurosEfeticosSACSimuladodois ="_";
  HtmlSacSimuladodois = "";


  SistemaAmortizacaoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  FaixaPRICESimuladodois = '_';
  ValorImovelPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  ValorEntradaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  DescontoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  PrazoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  FGTSTresAnoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  NumeroParticipantesPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  DependentesPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  RendaUsavaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  ValorFinanciamentoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  PrazoMaximoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  CotaMaxFinanciamentoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  EntradaAtualizadaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  DespesaCartorariaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  ApoliceSeguroPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  SeguroVistaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  TarifasPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  IOFPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  totalTaxasAVistaPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  AmortizacaoJurosPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  SeguroDFIPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  SeguroMIPPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  TotalSegurosPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  TaxaAdministracaoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  TaxaRiscoCreditoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  TaxaOperacionalMensalPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  TotalComponentesPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  PrimeiraPrestacaoPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  JurosNominaisPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  JurosEfeticosPRICESimuladodois ="_";
  HtmlPriceSimuladodois = "";

}
```

Does anyone have any idea what causes this behavior?

Comment: You can add async to wait to complete process for RAM in flutter

Comment: did you consider disposing all your TextEditingController ? TextEditingController must be dispose, it can cause memory leaks

Comment: i removed all the TextEditingController

and same behavior keeps happening